# jquery set value on button submittion

Tags: php, jquery

problem

i have two button "YES" and "NO". if user click YES then text input will appear with value set ex: value="$check['sum'];" but when user click No then text input will appear without value ex: value ="".

here is my code

```
 <input id="test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>" value="<?php echo $value;?>" name="test" type="text" class="test" style="width:70px;display:none">
```

and jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#Yes<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").click(function(){ 
           $("#test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").show(1000);
         });
     $("#No<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").click(function(){
       $("#test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").hide(1000);
      });
```

thanks you

Comment: You can't have php inside javascript.  Is your javascript inside a `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the disabled attribute:

```
$("#test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

and

```
$("#test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#YES").click(function(){
        $("#test").show(); //value of input as set before. so, just show
    }
    $("#NO").click(function(){
        $("#test").attr('value','').show(); //set value = '' , and show
    }
});
```

Comment: yes working but how if i want to set value on YES $("#test").attr('value','<?php echo $row['sum');?>.show(); ??

Answer (score 0):

Use binding function so that you provide your JS code with exact parameters. Code like yours **should never be used**.

Object ID or class should contain alphanumerical characters only, should not begin with number(s), and optionally, - or _ might be used. Avoid spaces or, as you've already shown yourself, using embedded PHP code which is highly unlikely to work in any further project of yours. It's also dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

instead of this code `$("#Yes<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>")`

try the following

`$("#test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>")`.

Because you used id of button as "`test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>`". so only your click event not worked.